# What executes earlier, return or ++?

Tags: c++

```
class x
{
 public:
  int y;
  x& operator++(int);

};
```

I want the foo(), that works like:

```
int& foo()
{
  int& ret_val = x.y;
  x++;
  return ret_val;
}
```

but looks like:

```
int& foo()
{
  return (x++).y;
}
```

Is this possible? What is executed earlier, return or ++?

ok, thx for your answers.

"rather a copy of the object in the state prior to the increment (i.e.- your x& operator++(int) doesnt follow the convention)"
Can I write operator++(int) follow the convention? and how do it be written?

Then can I write function like this:

```
int foo() {return (x++).y;}
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question then whatever is to the right of the return will be evaluated first.  So the ++ is going to "execute" before anything is returned

Comment: If you follow the standard C++ convention, the post-increment operator (x++) should not return the object being incremented, but rather a copy of the object in the state prior to the increment (i.e.- your x& operator++(int) doesnt follow the convention).  The prefix increment operator (++x) returns the original object incremented.

Answer (score 8):

The `++` executes before the return, but the return *value* is fixed *before* the `++`.  I started to write out the equivalent code but then I realized your middle example is already the same as what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

The ++ operator will be executed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your final implementation is wrong, and should not compile, because you are trying to form a non-const reference to a temporary.  There are many cases of dangling references, all of which are incorrect, but this one at least can be caught by the compiler.